# synchronizing on the same object has issues?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am not able to understand the below code mentioned in slide 15 of [slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/alexmiller/java-concurrency-gotchas-3666977#!)

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    synchronized(obj) {
        obj= new MyObject();
        // no longer synchronizing on the same object
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this is a BS example. I guess there must have been somebody wrote a bug like this once, but it's either a pretty stupid bug or pretty stupid code.

Comment: @ThomasW true: +1. I've never seen anyone make such mistake

Comment: @ThomasW Looking at the link of the slideshow OP gave. The title of the slide clearly says "DO NOT: change instance" followed by some example code of changing instance which the OP posted here.

Comment: This is possibly a good example of why you should, where possible, use `static final` lock objects :P

Answer (score 2):

At the first declaration of MyObject obj, the 'obj' object has been assigned to a new instance of MyObject.

Entering the synchronization block, java holds a reference to 'obj' for itself to use as the locking object.

Inside the synchronization block the reference your program holds has been redefined to another new instance of MyObject. At this point, the original reference pointing to the original instance of MyObject has been lost and replaced by a reference to a new instance of MyObject.

Any further sync blocks that come up using 'obj' will be locking on the new instance of the object and not the old one, thus no longer synchronizing on the same object.

To prevent issues like this I generally mark all my lock objects as final as to prevent accidental redefinition.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in the first and second line you are creating a new instance of the `MyObject` and synchronizing it.

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    synchronized(obj) {
```

But the problem is that at third line you override `obj` variable value assigning to it a reference of a new instance of `MyObject`. The result is that you have two instances of `MyObject` in the memory, but the variable `obj` refer only to last one (which is not synchronized).

Comment: Just to add to that remember the old school Java rule `Object reference are passed by value in java`